# Not able to setup connection.url for kafka connect setup for oracle

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ojdbc

I am trying to setup a pipeline to stream data from oracle database and put it into a topic.I connect to this database using below tnsnames.ora file on my local. Please do notice, this database is not on localhost.

**tnsnames.ora :**

```
DV06 = (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =dev-db.uc.com)(PORT = 5222))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = devdbsc.uc.com)))
```

I am using `lensesio/fast-data-dev` image for all required Kafka service and running everything under Docker.

**Steps to create a connector :**

**Step 1 :**

**Identify jar path :**

As I am trying to connect to oracle database, First thing I tried to look for Kafka-connect-jdbc* so that I can download and place odbc jar in the same folder.

```
root@fast-data-dev / $  find / -name kafka-connect-jdbc\*.jar
/opt/landoop/connectors/third-party/kafka-connect-jdbc/kafka-connect-jdbc-5.2.3.jar
root@fast-data-dev / $
```

**Step 2:**

**Place jar file :**

The next step is to download odbc jar and place in same path. I have downloaded it from Maven repository and place it in the same folder: ojdbc8-12-2.0.1.jar

```
root@fast-data-dev / $ ls opt/landoop/connectors/third-party/kafka-connect-jdbc/
audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar  jline-0.9.94.jar              mariadb-java-client-2.2.1.jar  postgresql-9.4.1212.jar  sqlite-jdbc-3.25.2.jar
common-utils-5.2.3.jar          jtds-1.3.1.jar                netty-3.10.6.Final.jar         sample-config            zkclient-0.10.jar
doc                             kafka-connect-jdbc-5.2.3.jar  ojdbc8-12-2.0.1.jar            slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar     zookeeper-3.4.13.jar
root@fast-data-dev / $
```

**Step 3 :**

**Create connector:**

I tried two options with `connection.url`.

**Option 1:**

```
 curl -X POST "http://localhost:8083/connectors" -H "Content-type:application/json" --data \
    '{
        "name" : "orc_source",
        "config" : {
            "connector.class" : "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
            "connection.url" : "jdbc:oracle:thin:@dev-db.uc.com:5222,
            "connection.user":"FG",
            "connection.password":"1234",
            "mode":"bulk",
            "topic.prefix": "oracle_",
            "table.whitelist":"DRVR_TBL",
            "poll.interval.ms":10000
            }
    }'
```

**Option 2:**

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8083/connectors" -H "Content-type:application/json" --data \
        '{
            "name" : "orc_source",
            "config" : {
                "connector.class" : "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
                "connection.url" : "jdbc:oracle:thin:@dev-db.uc.com:5222/devdbsc.uc.com,
                "connection.user":"FG",
                "connection.password":"1234",
                "mode":"bulk",
                "topic.prefix": "oracle_",
                "table.whitelist":"DRVR_TBL",
                "poll.interval.ms":10000
                }
        }'
```

But in both cases, I am getting below error :

```
"error_code":400,"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s):\nInvalid value java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@dev-db.uc.com:5222 for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:oracle:thin:@dev-db.uc.com:5222\nInvalid value java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@dev-db.uc.com:5222 for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:oracle:thin:@dev-db.uc.com:52221\nYou can also find the above list of errors at
the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate`"}.
```

It seems like there is some problem the way I am passing the connection.url but not sure where it's going wrong. please suggest.

Comment: Have you reviewed https://rmoff.dev/fix-jdbc-driver-video? that covers this issue

Comment: Yes, I have followed the same step and placed jar accordingly where Kafka-connect-jdbc jar is present. But, as mentioned in the video, this could occur because of the wrong connection url also. That's something I want to confirm.

Comment: What's the full error that you get? You've only quoted part of it

Comment: Hi Robin, I have updated same in my post.